# Is it possible to run this function without ng-app being used?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My AngularJS application has 2 ng-app tags in the html, and from research it looks like this means only the first one gets ran.

I have this method here

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js">
</script>
<script>
    var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);

    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
        $http({
            method : "GET",
            url : "http://localhost:5050/get_time"
        }).then(function successCallBack(response) {
            $scope.jsonResponse = response.data;
        }, function errorCallBack(response) {
            $scope.jsonResponse = "failed"
        });
        angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("App"), ['MyApp']);
    });
</script>
<div ng-app = "MyApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <p>Response of JSON Below:</p>
    <h1>{{jsonResponse}}</h1>

</div>
```

as you can see this line here

```
<div ng-app = "MyApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
```

Basically I just need my function to work without using ng-app is this possible?

Comment: I think you miss understand about how to use angularjs as a framework in your application. Please update your question with what you want to do!? I don't think you will need two app in the app.

Answer (score 0):

To bootstrap a second app, use `angular.bootstrap`:

```
<div id="app2" ng-controller="myCtrl">    
    <p>Response of JSON Below:</p>
    <h1>{{jsonResponse}}</h1>    
</div>
```

```js
angular.module("MyApp", [])
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http({
        method : "GET",
        url : "http://localhost:5050/get_time"
    }).then(function successCallBack(response) {
        $scope.jsonResponse = response.data;
    }, function errorCallBack(response) {
        $scope.jsonResponse = "failed"
    });
});

angular.element(function () {
    angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("app2"), ['MyApp']);
});
```

From the Docs:

> ## Things to keep in mind
>
> There are a few things to keep in mind regardless of automatic or manual bootstrapping:
>
> - While it's possible to bootstrap more than one AngularJS application per page, we don't actively test against this scenario. It's possible that you'll run into problems, especially with complex apps, so caution is advised.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Manual Initialization](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap#manual-initialization)
- [AngularJS angular.bootstrap Function API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap)

Comment: its just saying {{jsonResponse}} its not even running the second one :( any advice ? its basically skippig over the method